# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to update a string field

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin

I have my database set up in phpMyAdmin and in my query below I am trying to update a string field that contains the file path of some software for example something like 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Total Security 19.0.0\avp.exe'.

When I execute the query i get the java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException as seen below. This query works just fine when running it in phpMyAdmin itself. What am I doing wrong?

My query:

```
String query4 = MessageFormat.format("UPDATE system_object SET file_path = {0}, validate={1} " +
            "where category_key = 2", settings.getAntivirus_filePath(), settings.isAntivirus_validate());
```

The error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':\Program Files (x86)Kaspersky LabKaspersky Total Security 19.0.0avp.exe, valida' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1355)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2128)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1264)
    at s4.server.resourcemonitor.dao.ServerResourcesDAO.savePCSettings(ServerResourcesDAO.java:307)
    at s4.server.resourcemonitor.controller.ServerResourcesController.savePCSettings(ServerResourcesController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT**
I did try to use quotes on my parameters but then I just get the same kind of error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0}, validate=true where category_key = 2' at line 1
```

Comment: Not sure but there is a strange that your message has not been filled the argument. I guess there are something wrong with your `settings.getAntivirus_filePath()` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters; your current approach is vulnerable to sql injection. Ignoring that concern (and it is a big concern), you aren't quoting your parameters. You could do

```
String query4 = MessageFormat.format(
        "UPDATE system_object SET file_path = '{0}', validate='{1}' " +
        "where category_key = 2", settings.getAntivirus_filePath(), 
        settings.isAntivirus_validate());
```

Comment: I did try to quote them, but just get a similar error

Comment: Quoting them won't work in this case since `MessageFormat` will see it as literal text. `PreparedStatement` is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using prepared statements and it is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: That is, remove the call to MessageFormat from the code.  You are doing the statement parameter binding using MessageFormat, which is simply not intended for that purpose.  What's intended for the purpose is PreparedStatement.setParameter(...).

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to this :

```
String query4 = MessageFormat.format(
            "UPDATE system_object SET file_path = \"{0}\", validate=\"{1}\" " +
            "where category_key = 2", "demo1", 
            "demo2");
    System.out.println(query4);
```

Output : `UPDATE system_object SET file_path = "demo1", validate="demo2" where category_key = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Just an update use double '' instead of single ' :

```
String query4 = MessageFormat.format(
        "UPDATE system_object SET file_path = '{0}', validate='{1}' " +
        "where category_key = 2", settings.getAntivirus_filePath(), 
        settings.isAntivirus_validate());
```